# Calling custom plugin class methods from a template

Tags: plugins, page-template, oop

Is it possible to call instance methods of a class from a template file that is loaded by that class? If I try to invoke `$this` from the template, I get `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context` and invoking everything statically defeats the purpose of classes.

In other words, is it possible to get the template file below to call a public method in instance of a `WP_Widget` subclass the same way I can call `the_title()`?

#### CustomPluginTemplate.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <div>
        <p><?php callSomeClassMethodHere() ?></p>
    </div>
</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

#### CustomPlugin.php

```
<?php

/*
Plugin Name: My Custom Plugin
Description: This is a test plugin
Version: 0.0.1
*/

class CustomPlugin extends \WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'CustomPlugin', // ID
            __('Custom Plugin', 'text_domain'), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'This is a custom plugin', 'text_domain' )) // Description
        );

        add_action('init', array($this, 'init'), 10, 0);
        add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'query_vars'));
        add_action('page_template', array($this, 'page_template'));
    }

    public function init() {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            '^custom-page/([^/]*)',
            'index.php?page_id=2&custom_id=$matches[1]',
            'top'
        );

    }

    public function query_vars($query_vars) {
        $query_vars[] = 'custom_id';

        return $query_vars;
    }

    public function page_template($path = '') {
        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/CustomPluginTemplate.php';

        return $path;
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', function () { register_widget('CustomPlugin'); });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just instantiate an object from class `CustomPlugin` like `$obj = new CustomPlugin('id','name','desc');` in `CustomPluginTemplate.php`

and call any method from the class within the `CustomPluginTemplate.php` file as `$obj->query_vars();`

Before instantiating make sure you class is included.